# What is the actual definition of "matrix representation in another basis"?

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, definition

A common type of question in linear algebra textbooks are these:

> Let $A = \begin{bmatrix} a_{11} & a_{12} \\ a_{21} & a_{22}
>  \end{bmatrix}$ and consider a basis $B = \left\{b_1 = \begin{bmatrix} b_{11}
>  \\ b_{12} \end{bmatrix}, b_2 = \begin{bmatrix} b_{21} \\ b_{22}
>  \end{bmatrix}\right\}$
>
> **Find the matrix representation of A in basis**

So what is the definition of: **Matrix representation of A in basis** ?

After some digging, I found an unsatisfactory definition:

> The matrix representation of $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ in basis
> $B$ is the matrix $\widetilde A = [\widetilde a_{ji}]$ such that,
>
> \begin{equation} A b_i = \sum\limits_{j = 1}^n {\widetilde a_{ji}}
>  b_i, \forall i = 1, \ldots, n \end{equation}

There seems to be little or no motivation at all behind this definition. For instance, why am I multiplying $A$ by a basis vector $b_i$ and not any arbitrary vector? Certainly, any $Ax$, $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, could be represented in the basis $B$, no?

Can someone provide a good definition to **Matrix representation of A in basis**  and I would appreciate it if a reference is included.

Comment: That is the definition, there isn't another one. The point is that by definition, every vector is a unique linear combination of elements of a basis. So knowing how $A$ acts on a basis tells you how it acts on every vector.

Comment: That is extremely poor wording.  What is meant is that we have an $\mathbb{F}$-linear transformation $\alpha\colon V\to V$ that is represented by the matrix $A$ with respect to some basis $v_1,v_2$ of $V$ (in this case $\dim_\mathbb{F} V=2$).  What would be the matrix if we write $\alpha$ relative to another basis $\mathscr{B}=(b_1=b_{11}v_1+b_{12}v_2,b_2=b_{21}v_1+b_{22}v_2)$  of $V$ instead?

Comment: Given a matrix $A$, its representation in a basis $V = (v_1,\ldots,v_n)$ is a matrix $B$ that takes $V$-coordinates of any element $v$ to the $V$ coordinates of $Av$. In terms of notations let's say

$v = a_1v_1 + \ldots + a_nv_n = \begin{bmatrix}v_1&\ldots&v_n\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}a_1\\ \vdots \\ a_n\end{bmatrix}$

Then $[a_1,\ldots, a_n]'$ is what you call the coordinates of $v$ with respect to the basis $V$ which I called $V$-coordinates. Now let's say

$Av =b_1v_1 + \ldots + b_nv_n $

Comment: ...Then matrix $B$ must send $[a_1,\ldots, a_n]'$ to $[b_1,\ldots, b_n]'$. In notations it means

$B \begin{bmatrix}a_1\\ \vdots \\ a_n\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}b_1\\ \vdots \\ b_n\end{bmatrix}$

A compact way to put it is as follows

$Av = A \begin{bmatrix}v_1&\ldots&v_n\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}a_1\\ \vdots \\ a_n\end{bmatrix} = b_1v_1 + \ldots + b_nv_n = \begin{bmatrix}v_1&\ldots&v_n\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}b_1\\ \vdots \\ b_n\end{bmatrix} =  \begin{bmatrix}v_1&\ldots&v_n\end{bmatrix} B\begin{bmatrix}a_1\\ \vdots \\ a_n\end{bmatrix}    $

Comment: ...Thus ultimately

$A \begin{bmatrix}v_1&\ldots&v_n\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}a_1\\ \vdots \\ a_n\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}v_1&\ldots&v_n\end{bmatrix} B\begin{bmatrix}a_1\\ \vdots \\ a_n\end{bmatrix}    $

For all $[a_1,\ldots, a_n]'.$ This in particular will give you


$A \begin{bmatrix}v_1&\ldots&v_n\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}v_1&\ldots&v_n\end{bmatrix} B  $

Comment: @TonyPizza This is excellent, why not put it as an answer?

Comment: I didn't put it as answer because it is most certainly a duplicate and even though I think the way I put it deserves a mention of its own, I have seen people on this platform have problem quickly if I answer a seemingly duplicate or a seemingly simple question or many other things.

Comment: I notice that you put linear-transformations in your tag list, but you did not address linear transformations in your post. What I would say is that this definition is motivated by the fact that for any linear transformation $T : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$, there is a matrix representations of $T$ associated to any choice of basis of $\mathbb R^n$ and of $\mathbb R^m$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a matrix $A$, its representation in a basis $V = (v_1,\ldots,v_n)$ is a matrix $B$ that takes $V$-coordinates of any element $v$ to the $V$ coordinates of $Av$. In terms of notations let's say

$v = a_1v_1 + \ldots + a_nv_n = \begin{bmatrix}v_1&\ldots&v_n\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}a_1\\ \vdots \\ a_n\end{bmatrix}$

Then $[a_1,\ldots, a_n]'$ is what you call the coordinates of $v$ with respect to the basis $V$ which I called $V$-coordinates. Now let's say

$Av =b_1v_1 + \ldots + b_nv_n $

Then matrix $B$ must send $[a_1,\ldots, a_n]'$ to $[b_1,\ldots, b_n]'$. In notations it means

$B \begin{bmatrix}a_1\\ \vdots \\ a_n\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}b_1\\ \vdots \\ b_n\end{bmatrix}$

A compact way to put it is as follows

$Av = A \begin{bmatrix}v_1&\ldots&v_n\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}a_1\\ \vdots \\ a_n\end{bmatrix} = b_1v_1 + \ldots + b_nv_n = \begin{bmatrix}v_1&\ldots&v_n\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}b_1\\ \vdots \\ b_n\end{bmatrix} =  \begin{bmatrix}v_1&\ldots&v_n\end{bmatrix} B\begin{bmatrix}a_1\\ \vdots \\ a_n\end{bmatrix}    $

Thus ultimately

$A \begin{bmatrix}v_1&\ldots&v_n\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}a_1\\ \vdots \\ a_n\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}v_1&\ldots&v_n\end{bmatrix} B\begin{bmatrix}a_1\\ \vdots \\ a_n\end{bmatrix}    $

For all $[a_1,\ldots, a_n]'.$ This in particular will give you

$A \begin{bmatrix}v_1&\ldots&v_n\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}v_1&\ldots&v_n\end{bmatrix} B  $